# With Firefox, open .vi files from web pages directly with LabVIEW

Tags: firefox, vi, file-types, mime-types, labview

I use Firefox (now 98.0.1; March 2022) and Windows 10.
In the recent past (i.e., Feb 2022), when I clicked on a web link to a vi, it used to open the file in LabVIEW directly.
Now, Firefox instead requires me to save the vi as a first step... making this a three step process instead of the 1 step process it used to be.
In the firefox "settings", ".vi" is not listed as a valid file type, and I don't see an obvious way of adding any new file types to force vi files to open in LabVIEW. All the help pages that Google sent me to for adding new file types contained out-of-date information from 10 years ago that don't work.
For example these didn't help:
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1235051
https://www.watchingthenet.com/how-to-configure-firefox-to-open-different-types-of-files.html

... and many others.

It probably goes without saying that my PC itself *does* recognize that vi files should open in LabVIEW:
[Windows 10 Default application for .vi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJ8Ok.png)

If this problem requires that the web site that's "serving" the vi must report a MIME type, I'd like to find out what the proper MIME type is supposed to be... I can't seem to find any info about this, even though it worked (automatically) a couple of weeks ago. I suspect that there's some line to be added to the server's .htaccess file, but I don't know what that text should be...

My computer *does* have a copy of a mimetypes.rdf file, but it's in a "thunderbird" folder, not a firefox folder, and I'm not sure that Firefox looks at it. Also, it's empty anyway.

In summary:
a. How can I add a new filetype to Firefox?,
or b. What's the proper MIME type to be served with a .vi (LabVIEW) file?

Answer (score 0):

Firefox, over time has changed the file storing its *MIME* types. Currently (v. 96 and later), these are stored in the user's profile as *handlers.json*. The file can be edited with a text editor, or far more easily, with a dedicate JSON editing app, such as free [JSONedit](http://tomeko.net/software/JSONedit/).

[image: handlers.json in JSONedit]

To add a new handler, e.g., *LabView*:

- Open *handlers.json* in an editor.
- Add an object node for *application/vi* (or other name).
- Add an integer node, *action*. Set the value to `2` to make Firefox start an external application (set it to *0* to automatically download the file).
- Add  an array node, *extensions*.
- Set the zeroth node to *vi*; no leading period is used.
- Add an array node, *handlers*.
- In the zeroth node, add a string object, *name*, and set it to the filename of *LabView*.
- In the zeroth node, add a string object, *path*, with the *full* path to *Labview*.
- Save the edited JSON file.

Likely, you'll need to restart *Firefox* for this change to be recognized.